# The command "flutter doctor" cannot locate Flutter and Dart plugins installed in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, android-studio-plugin

I am new to the Flutter development environment. I downloaded the flutter and dart sdk and have added their path to the environment variable in the ~/.bashrc file. I am using Android studio for developing Flutter apps. I installed the Flutter and Dart plugins in Android Studio but when I am running the command `flutter doctor` it gives the following error:

[image: flutter doctor command issue]

Flutter and Dart Plugins installed in Android Studio

[image: Flutter and Dart Plugins Installed]

I have no idea why `flutter doctor` cannot detect the plugins installed for Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart android studio after the installation of plugins, then run flutter doctor.

If it doesn't help, maybe the path of your android sdk is not set properly.

- Get path of android sdk by going to **Android Studio > Preferences** and then find for sdk as shown in the picture. It should look like `/Users/yourName/Library/Android/sdk`

  [image]
- run the command `flutter config --android-sdk PATH_TO_ANDROID_SDK` in your terminal.

Once done, restart your machine and run flutter doctor.

Comment: I restarted Android Studio but still it is giving me the same issue.

Comment: -Uninstall Dart and flutter
-Restart android studio or intellij
-Install Dart and flutter and restart again

Comment: Which version of android studio are u using?

Comment: Android Studio v3.5.3

Comment: Have you set the path to your android sdk?

Comment: The android sdk path is set in Android Studio. Do I have to specify the path in the PATH environment variable in ~/.bashrc file also?

Comment: No, but to flutter configurations. Wait I will update my answer.

Comment: I used the command flutter config --android-sdk /home/PATH_TO_SDK/Android/Sdk and restarted my machine but it is still giving me the same issue as I posted.